# Load() not working to call a PHP template when submitting a form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load a php file into a div on submission of a form. At the moment everything fires bar this line `$('#signupform').load('newsletter-signup-call.php');`, I've just got a simple echo request in there and it doesn't fire. If I goto that template it works though.

Where am I going wrong? Could I possibly fire two Ajax calls (as that in itself works) but there seems to be issues with `load`.

```
  <script>
    $("#signupForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var email = $("#EmailAddress").val();

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: form.attr('action') + '?email=' + email,
               data: form.serialize(),
               beforeSend: function(){
                 $(".newsletter-loading").show().css({"display":"inline-block"});
               },
               success: function(data)
               {
                   console.log(data); //data contain response from your php script
                   register_signup();
                   register_prefs();

                   (function() {
                       window.sib = {
                           equeue: [],
                           client_key: "xxx"
                       };
                       /* OPTIONAL: email for identify request*/
                       window.sib.email_id = email;
                       window.sendinblue = {};
                       for (var j = ['track', 'identify', 'trackLink', 'page'], i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                       (function(k) {
                           window.sendinblue[k] = function() {
                               var arg = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
                               (window.sib[k] || function() {
                                       var t = {};
                                       t[k] = arg;
                                       window.sib.equeue.push(t);
                                   })(arg[0], arg[1], arg[2]);
                               };
                           })(j[i]);
                       }
                       var n = document.createElement("script"),
                           i = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
                       n.type = "text/javascript", n.id = "sendinblue-js", n.async = !0, n.src = "https://sibautomation.com/sa.js?key=" + window.sib.client_key, i.parentNode.insertBefore(n, i), window.sendinblue.page();
                   })();

                   sendinblue.track('marketing');
                   $(".newsletter-loading").hide();
                   form.replaceWith("<br /><p>Thanks for signing up! You'll receive an email with your discount.</p>");
               }
             });

    });
    function register_prefs(){
      var email = $("#EmailAddress").val();
      Cookies.set('Address', email, { expires: 100000 });
      $('#signupform').load('newsletter-signup-call.php');
    }

    function register_signup(){
      ga( 'send', 'event', 'Newsletter Sign Up', 'submit' );
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean that line "doesn't fire"?  Is the `register_prefs()` function invoked at all?  Is there an error in the browser console?  Is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  Where is your `#signupform` element?  What happens to it?

Comment: @David The function is invoked because it adds the cookie. Ajax call also works because it does all my other functionality. I don't seem to get any errors which is annoying. I was half expecting it to just echo out "test" but that doesn't appear. The issue just seems the `load` part.

Comment: *"Ajax call also works because it does all my other functionality."* - What "other functionality"?  All `.load()` does is add the response to the target element.  So what is the response?  In your browser's debugging tools, check the network requests.  *"I was half expecting..."* - So you're not sure what it should be doing?

Comment: @David The functionality for Send in Blue within the ajax call works fine, so that's the other functionality. I've just put an echo within the `load()` file just to make sure it works, it doesn't appear to fire as nothing is loaded in the network part of my browser.

Comment: If the `register_prefs()` function begins execution, but `.load()` is never executed, then there *must* be an error which is stopping execution somewhere.  If the result server-side functionality on `newsletter-signup-call.php` is invoked at that time then an AJAX request *must* be getting executed, so there *must* be an HTTP request in the browser's debugging tools.  It sounds like there are some invalid assumptions or incorrect observations in the debugging here...

Comment: *"The functionality for Send in Blue within the ajax call works fine"* - Wait... *Which* AJAX call are you talking about?  What is "send in blue" in this case?  The question is about the call to `.load()`, not the call to `.ajax()`, right?  Forget all of that "send in blue" stuff above it, what is the request/response for the AJAX call in `.load()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to console.log the response status to see what's going wrong

```
function register_prefs(){

    //see if this function is triggered 
    console.log('register_prefs function triggered')

    var email = $("#EmailAddress").val();
    Cookies.set('Address', email, { expires: 100000 });

    $('#signupform').load('newsletter-signup-call.php', function( response, status, xhr ){
        console.log('Server response : ', response)//The serve response
        console.log('Status Message : ', [xhr.status, xhr.statusText])//See the status of your request, if any error it should be displayed here
    });
}
```

BUT, Why perform another server call with load, when your are already using ajax, you can return the html in the first call in a json object `{Mydata: ..., MyHTML: ...}`  and just use `$('#signupform').html(data.MyHTML)` on success.

Also, not sure but I'm suspecting a malformed URL, try this instead '/newsletter-signup-call.php' or an absolute path just to be sure.